# Retrieving names of high level JSON arrays with jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, json, object

I am working with JSON data with multiple sets of key value pairs - each set constitutes a list. In the simplified example below,  The list name is not known beforehand - actually I'll need to populate a select dropdown on the page with the names of each list. How do I retrieve the set names in this situation?

```
({
 "list1": 
 [{
     "prodRating": "5",
     "prodReviews": "21"
 },
        {
     "prodRating": "5",
     "prodReviews": "21"
 }],
 "list2": 
 [{
     "prodRating": "5",
     "prodReviews": "21"
 },
        {
     "prodRating": "5",
     "prodReviews": "21"
 }]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = ... //something which gets you the json data
for (var listname in json)
    alert(listname)
```

Would display two alerts in this case saying "list1" and "list2".

Here a little sample page which iterates over an object which is built like yours but the "labels" don't have to be known.

And creates two selects dynamically

http://jsbin.com/azeha

Answer (score 0):

JSON key pairs that you show here is like Map with list of JSON object reference by key, "listX". You can iterate them with the key value:

```
var test = {"list1": 
                 [{
                     "prodRating": "5",
                     "prodReviews": "21"
                 },
                        {
                     "prodRating": "5",
                     "prodReviews": "21"
                 }],
                 "list2": 
                 [{
                     "prodRating": "5",
                     "prodReviews": "21"
                 },
                        {
                     "prodRating": "5",
                     "prodReviews": "21"
                 }]
                };
    for (var i in test){
        console.log("Key: "+ i); 
        for(var j in test[i]){
            var something = test[i][j]; 
            console.log("Rating: " + something.prodRating + " Reviews: " + something.prodReviews); 
        }
    }
```

Not sure how you want to layout your drop down. But you can use jquery's [html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) to generate the html. Hope it helps.